# Is it always possible to make a non-diagonalizable matrix diagonalizable by row scaling only?

Tags: diagonalization

Suppose $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a non-diagonalizable matrix and, if $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is singular, zero eigenvalue is simple, is it always possible to find a diagonal matrix $D\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ with nonzero diagonal entries such that $DA$ is diagonalizable?

I thought the answer was yes, but I cannot prove it, nor find exact statements in the textbook that support my thought. If the answer is yes, please provide some resources to retrieve the anwser or some hints to prove it.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is negative. Take $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. Its only eigenvalue is $0$. If $D=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a&0\\0&b\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, with $a,b\neq0$, then$$DA=\begin{pmatrix}0&a\\0&0\end{pmatrix},$$which is not diagonalizable.

Comment: Thanks! Here is a prerequisite, i.e., $A$ only has one zero eigenvalue, so the example is not the one I mean. BTW, I still require the diagonal entries of $D$ to be nonzero, which is missing in the original question. I have added it.

Comment: @Xianwei I don't understand. My matrix $A$ has one and only one eigenvalue, which is $0$. What's the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your further your clarification. Quite sorry for my inexact statement. I mean 0 is a simple eigenvalue, that is, the algebraic multiplicity of the zero eigenvalue is 1. I have made the correction in the question.

Comment: If all eigenvalues have algebraic multiplicity of $1$ then the matrix is diagonlizable. [if and only if, actually]

Comment: @Oria Gruber Thanks! Possibly relating to this fact, my question can be rephrased as: Is it always possible to find a diagonal matrix $D$ with nonzero diagonal entries such that all the eigenvalues of $DA$ have algebraic multiplicity of 1?